# Is there a way to input GPS co-ordinates into the iOS6 Maps app?

Tags: ios, maps

In Google Maps and the iOS-5 Maps app you can search for co-ordinates such as "loc: N 42 14.768 W 071 02.156" (note the lowercase loc). In the new Maps app this fails with No Results found. Is there another way to enter GPS co-ordinates or is this another missing 'feature'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Omit the "loc:" and just enter the coordinates.

40.748342, -73.984606 will drop a pin right on the Empire State Building.

Comment: Tested that out and it appears to work. Looks like it only supports decimal format rather than degrees and minutes. I do a lot of geocaching and that's how most co-ordinates are listed. I can convert them of course but just one more step (aka annoyance). Thanks.